# How turn off video in webrtc connection if camera not allowed or not found?

Tags: javascript, webrtc

I try this

```
peerConnection.createOffer({offerToReceiveAudio: 1, offerToReceiveVideo: 1});
```

But if camera not found or not allowed i get errors in my code. Now i can't get this offer on another computer.

Can you help me please? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think in this case you should check the availability of devices first by using javascript code.

If the user doesn't allow video or doesn't have a webcam/camera then the media-devices type will have the attribute with "null" value. FYI, you can also check it by typing **"DetectRTC.MediaDevices"** in developer tool of browser.

I found a demo for this : https://www.webrtc-experiment.com/DetectRTC/

You can read more in MDN web doc: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/getUserMedia

Comment: Fun in what my server not working if i not send new webrtcpeerconnection, i need send his without video or change his on image, i try install poster but client not connected on server.